# Error using SELECT DISTINCT() with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, sql-order-by

I'm facing a problem when using SELECT DISTINCT() with ORDER BY...
Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t2)
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.t2 = t2.id
JOIN Table3 t3 ON t1.t3 = t3.id
JOIN Table4 t4 ON t2.t4 = t4.id
JOIN Table5 t5 ON t2.t5 = t5.id
JOIN Table6 t6 ON t2.t6 = t6.id
ORDER BY t4.date DESC
```

But it is wrong... You have any idea?

Thanks in advance! =)

Comment: What's wrong? What are you expecting? Which table is t2 in? Using table alias that match column names is a bad idea.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is a keyword, not a function. It applies to the entire SELECT list. (The parens around `t2` are superfluous).  The value of `t4.date` is not available in the ORDER BY clause because it's not included in the SELECT DISTINCT list. Use a GROUP BY clause instead of DISTINCT.

Answer (score 2):

In a `SELECT DISTINCT` query, you can only order by the columns that are in the `SELECT`.  After all, what value of `date` should be used for the ordering?

Okay, I might guess . . . the maximum.  So, use aggregation:

```
SELECT t2
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN
     Table2 t2 ON t1.t2 = t2.id JOIN
     Table3 t3 ON t1.t3 = t3.id JOIN
     Table4 t4 ON t2.t4 = t4.id JOIN
     Table5 t5 ON t2.t5 = t5.id JOIn
     Table6 t6 ON t2.t6 = t6.id
GROUP BY t2
ORDER BY MAX(t4.date) DESC;
```

Comment: We'd prefer that the references to column `t2` be qualified  with the table alias (`t1.t2`)  both the SELECT list and the GROUP BY. +10.

Answer (score 0):

Your t2 is just and alias of your table and it can't be done like that:

It should be like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.*,t3.*,t4.*
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
JOIN Table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.id
JOIN Table4 t4 ON t2.id = t4.id
JOIN Table5 t5 ON t2.id = t5.id
JOIN Table6 t6 ON t2.id = t6.id
ORDER BY t4.date DESC
```

You have to be careful with same column name if you are using * because it returns an ambiguous error.. you can simply like t3.column1 and so on..

Comment: this query simply return a result if your table id is related to it's every table. you can change it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a subquery

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM Table1 t1
    JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.t2 = t2.id
    JOIN Table3 t3 ON t1.t3 = t3.id
    JOIN Table4 t4 ON t2.t4 = t4.id
    JOIN Table5 t5 ON t2.t5 = t5.id
    JOIN Table6 t6 ON t2.t6 = t6.id
    )
ORDER BY t4.date DESC
```